# Files saved with Ubuntu is not visible in Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, ntfs

Files saved with Ubuntu  is not visible in Windows 10.
Partition - NTFS partition.

When I open it from Ubuntu, it shows.
How do I fix it

Comment: Yeah, the Windows 10 anniversary update changed NTFS a bit, and NTFS-3G doesn't play real nicely with it.

Comment: Can't I fix it ?

Comment: Do you have fast startup disabled in Windows 10?

Comment: I think, I didn't.

Comment: Okay, then disable it, and make sure to actually shut down Windows, and not hibernate.

Comment: I haven't good knowledge about computer. OK.  Give me steps. I will do it.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/843161/518562

Comment: I did it and restart PC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56599/discussion-between-eshan-malimbada-and-android-dev).